# Formula to Split Cells and add additional row with that data in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets

Wondering if anyone can help.

Essential I need a google sheets formula that will transform the data in the first table to the second table. In column 1 split any numbers separated by ",", put the data in a new row underneath and then copy the data in the rest of the columns next to the data in column 1, see the table 2 what it should look like.

I've got the formula below and it works well:

=ArrayFormula(LET(range, CurrentTable!A2:F, headers, OFFSET(range,-1,,1,), col_1, INDEX(range,,1), col_2, INDEX(range,,2), combine, TOCOL(SPLIT(FILTER(IF((col_1="") * (col_2<>""), "X", col_1), col_2<>""), ", ", 1, 0)&"~"& BYROW(FILTER(OFFSET(range,,1,,COLUMNS(range)-1), col_2<>""), LAMBDA(r, JOIN("~", r))), 1), list, SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(combine, NOT(REGEXMATCH(combine, "^~"))), "^X", ""), "~", 1, 0), {headers; list}))

But I need to amend the formula to do 3 additional things:

1. I need it to ignore blanks in Col1, right now it just brings it back as is.
2. I want it to exclude any fields that don't contain a number or a combination of numbers (i.e 23,34,22), so I want to exclude any words (such as Not allocated, but it could be any word) etc. Not simple as include just numeric value as 23,34,22 isn't strictly a numeric value.
3. I want to a new column created and populated with 'Sub Div1', if that is present in col2. Thanks.

Table 1

| Area Code | City | Account Name | Account Number | Color | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Dallas | Ford | 10001 | Red | 2004 |
| 99,68 | Houston | Toyota | 10002 | Blue | 2005 |
| 70 | San Diego | Land Rover | 10003 | Green | 2006 |
| 73 | Sub Div3 - Seattle | Mini | 10004 | Black | 2007 |
| 78 | Auburn , Birmingham & Little Rock | Bentley | 10005 | Purple | 2008 |
| 9, 33 | Miami & Tampa | Nissan | 10006 | Yellow | 2009 |
| 110 | Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
| 73,9,33 | Sub Div1 - Chicago & Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
|  | Sub Div1 - Atlanta | Honda | 10009 | Pink | 2012 |
| 99,68 | Sub Div1 - Baton Rouge | Seat | 10010 | Grey | 2013 |
| Not Allocated | Sub Div2 - Boston/New York/Washington | GM | 10011 | White | 2014 |

Table 2

| Area Code | SD | City | Account Name | Account Number | Color | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 |  | Dallas | Ford | 10001 | Red | 2004 |
| 99 |  | Houston | Toyota | 10002 | Blue | 2005 |
| 68 |  | Houston | Toyota | 10002 | Blue | 2005 |
| 70 |  | San Diego | Land Rover | 10003 | Green | 2006 |
| 73 |  | Sub Div3 - Seattle | Mini | 10004 | Black | 2007 |
| 78 |  | Auburn , Birmingham & Little Rock | Bentley | 10005 | Purple | 2008 |
| 9 |  | Miami & Tampa | Nissan | 10006 | Yellow | 2009 |
| 33 |  | Miami & Tampa | Nissan | 10006 | Yellow | 2009 |
| 110 |  | Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
| 73 | Sub Div1 | Sub Div1 - Chicago & Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
| 9 | Sub Div1 | Sub Div1 - Chicago & Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
| 33 | Sub Div1 | Sub Div1 - Chicago & Detroit | Tesla | 10007 | Orange | 2010 |
| 99 | Sub Div1 | Sub Div1 - Baton Rouge | Seat | 10010 | Grey | 2013 |
| 68 | Sub Div1 | Sub Div1 - Baton Rouge | Seat | 10010 | Grey | 2013 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Λ,index(reduce(wraprows(,7,),sequence(match(,0/(A2:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,let(Σ,split(index(A2:A,c),","),{a;
   {tocol(Σ),if(sequence(counta(Σ)),{ifna(regexextract(index(B2:B,c),"^Sub Div1")),index(B2:F,c)})}})))),
   {{A1,"SD",B1:F1};filter(Λ,--choosecols(Λ,1))})
```

[image]